# Female alien softcore or hardcore movie, cover shows a female leg on White House

Tags: story-identification, movie, aliens

Does anyone know what movie name where a female alien invades the USA or the world. I only remember a female leg stepping on the White House on the movie cover.

Comment: Welcome to SciFi.SE! I feel like this isn't going to be enough to go on, especially if by "softcore or hardcore", you mean it's a porno. Lord knows there are too many of them to go sifting through. Is there anything else (preferably SFW) that you remember about this movie?

Comment: Since there's practically no useful information, here's my two best guesses: Splice (2009) or Species (1995)

Comment: "Stepping on it," you mean like hovering right above it, (i.e. getting ready to stand on it) or crushing/smashing the white house?  Are you sure the leg was of an alien? Or could it have been one of the old 50-100ft tall woman movies.

Answer (score 4):

[*Bimbo Movie Bash*](http://imdb.com/title/tt0118724) is probably what you're looking for.

> A squadron of outer space bimbos decide to take revenge on the male chauvinists of Earth.

According to one review, this is actually a compilation of various space-based "bimbo" film clips with a bit of additional scenes to provide a framing device.

The cover doesn't really show her stepping on the White House but close enough for government work

[image: Image of a pair of female legs emerging from a portal, and firing a ray gun down into the White House]

Comment: For those curious, the film is [available on Tubi with ads](https://tubitv.com/movies/528783/bimbo-movie-bash).